# What does nlog maxLevel=off config option do when combined with other configuration targeting the same output?

Tags: configuration, nlog

I'm unsure of what the nlog "level=off" config option does when combined with other configuration targeting the same output like the config provided below:

```
<logger name="Name.Space.*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="console" final="true"/>
<logger name="Name.Space.*" maxLevel="off" writeTo="console" final="true"/>
```

What behaviour would such a configuration would achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means all logger output with LogLevel above `minLevel="Info"` (Info + Warn + Error + Fatal) should `writeTo="console"`, and because of `final="true"` then logger-output should not reach following rules:

```xml
<logger name="Name.Space.*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="console" final="true"/>
```

This means all logger output with LogLevel below `maxLevel="off"` (Trace + Debug + Info + Warn + Error + Fatal) should `writeTo="console"`, and because of `final="true"` then logger-output should not reach following rules:

```xml
<logger name="Name.Space.*" maxLevel="off" writeTo="console" final="true"/>
```

The result of using these two rules, is that all output coming from Logger-instances matching `name="Name.Space.*"` will `writeTo="console"` independent of LogLevel.

[maxLevel](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules) is usually used to suppress logging. Because many find the `maxLevel` somewhat confusing, then NLog v5 have now introduced the new [finalMinLevel](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Rules-FinalMinLevel).

Maybe you want to do this:

```xml
<logger name="Name.Space.*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="console" finalMinLevel="Off" />
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to make sense to me. Surely `maxLevel="off"` would prevent all logging to the console from the specified namespace.

Comment: Not sure I can give a better explanation of `maxLevel="off"` (Besides that it includes ALL loglevels, because `Off` is higher than `Fatal`). Again I can recommend taking a look at [finalMinLevel](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Rules-FinalMinLevel), where `finalMinLevel="Off"` means disable logger-output.

Comment: The main thing I wanted to know is what does that combination of configuration options do - what is the actual outcome of them both combined together?

Comment: @YungDeiza Already tried to explain what the individual rules does. The first rule captures output with `minLevel="Info"` (Info + Warn + Error + Fatal), and everything else flows down to the second rule that captures `maxLevel="off"` (Trace + Debug + Info + Error + Fatal)

Comment: So what happens in the application, all levels are logged?

Comment: @YungDeiza Yes. Output coming from Logger-instances matching `name="Name.Space.*"` will `writeTo="console"` independent of LogLevel.

Comment: Thanks for being explicit, I wanted to be sure.